# How to use mapGetter with vuex

Tags: javascript, vuex

I am using mapGetters and mapActions in my navbar but for some reason the mapGetters is returning "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined" even though im using them both the same way. Could someone help me spot my error, I am new to vuex and how this works.

Here are my files: 
Auth.js

```
const state = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    user: {},
    status: '',
    error: null
};

const getters = {
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
    authState: state => state.status,
    user: state => state.user,
    error: state => state.error
};

const actions = {
    // Login Action
    async login({
        commit
    }, user) {
        commit('auth_request');
        try {
            let res = await axios.post('/api/users/login', user)
            if (res.data.success) {
                const token = res.data.token;
                const user = res.data.user;
                // Store the token into the localstorage
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                // Set the axios defaults
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
                commit('auth_success', token, user);
            }
            return res;
        } catch (err) {
            commit('auth_error', err);
        }
    },
    // Register User
    async register({
        commit
    }, userData) {
        try {
            commit('register_request');
            let res = await axios.post('/api/users/register', userData);
            if (res.data.success !== undefined) {
                commit('register_success');
            }
            return res;
        } catch (err) {
            commit('register_error', err)
        }
    },
    // Get the user Profile
    async getProfile({
        commit
    }) {
        commit('profile_request');
        let res = await axios.get('/api/users/profile')
        commit('user_profile', res.data.user)
        return res;
    },
    // Logout the user
    async logout({
        commit
    }) {
        await localStorage.removeItem('token');
        commit('logout');
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
        router.push('/login');
        return
    }
};

const mutations = {
    auth_request(state) {
        state.error = null
        state.status = 'loading'
    },
    auth_success(state, token, user) {
        state.token = token
        state.user = user
        state.status = 'success'
        state.error = null
    },
    auth_error(state, err) {
        state.error = err.response.data.msg
    },
    register_request(state) {
        state.error = null
        state.status = 'loading'
    },
    register_success(state) {
        state.error = null
        state.status = 'success'
    },
    register_error(state, err) {
        state.error = err.response.data.msg
    },
    logout(state) {
        state.error = null
        state.status = ''
        state.token = ''
        state.user = ''
    },
    profile_request(state) {
        state.status = 'loading'
    },
    user_profile(state, user) {
        state.user = user
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
};
```

Store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import Auth from './Auth';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    Auth
  },
  state: {

  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {

  }
```

Navbar

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["isLoggedIn"])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["logout"]),
    logoutUser() {
      this.logout();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you passing the store as a config option when calling `new Vue`?

Comment: I edited the store file to show the imports and set up of the Vue(). The thing is that the mapActions is working but for some reason the mapGetters are not.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in the `new Vue` call rather than the `new Vuex.Store` call. I want to confirm that you are passing the store as a config option when you call `new Vue`.

Comment: To be honest im not sure if I am passing a config option. This is my first experience using Vue.

Comment: Try passing the store when calling `new Vue`. Example: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/todomvc/app.js, documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components

Comment: You were right. I thought imported it into the js file but never actually passed it into the Vue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must add a name to the module :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import Auth from './Auth';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    authModule: Auth
  },
  state: {

  },
  mutations: {

  },
  actions: {

  }
```

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('authModule' ,["isLoggedIn"])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('authModule' ,["logout"]),
    logoutUser() {
      this.logout();
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT**

Don't forget to import the store in your application:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import store from './store' // Importing the store


Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store, // Importing the store in the vue application
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: I believe this is only necessary if the module is using `namespaced: true`.

Comment: yeah, this did not make a difference.

Comment: Where do you import the store ? in the `main.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

My best practice is to access through object by naming them

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    isLoggedIn: 'Auth/isLoggedIn'
  })
}
```

P.S. Use please state to access items in objects. In getters you need to write logic

for example

```
...mapState({
  user: state => state.Auth.user
```